# I get TypeError: unhashable type: 'Series' when I try to create dummy variable with pd.get_dummies. Can someone please help me?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to create dummy variables using Google Colab and it shows TypeError: unhashable type: 'Series'

Here is my code:

```
    X = pd.get_dummies(
    X,
    columns=X.select_dtypes(include=["object", "category"]).columns.tolist(),
    drop_first=True,
)
```

... and here is the error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/arrays/categorical.py in __init__(self, values, categories, ordered, dtype, fastpath, copy)
    431             try:
--> 432                 codes, categories = factorize(values, sort=True)
    433             except TypeError as err:

8 frames
pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.factorize()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable._unique()

TypeError: unhashable type: 'Series'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/algorithms.py in factorize_array(values, na_sentinel, size_hint, na_value, mask)
    562     table = hash_klass(size_hint or len(values))
    563     uniques, codes = table.factorize(
--> 564         values, na_sentinel=na_sentinel, na_value=na_value, mask=mask
    565     )
    566 

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.factorize()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable._unique()

TypeError: unhashable type: 'Series'
```

Comment: What is `print(type(X))` before you run that line?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.